# Triggering an Angular $broadcast from a factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm running a Dashboard system, where widgets on a page will render some grids and charts. I'm now setting up something we call "Widget Linking", where clicking on a grid will go off to a chart widget and display the data related to the grid row I just clicked on.

**Example: "linking a treelist (parent widget) to a bar chart (child widget) "**

In this example, I have `Kendo treelist` `select` event, which will pass the currently-selected row off to my `widgetLinkingFactory` factor. This factory should iterate through all available widgets on my page to see if any charts (child widgets) are linked to this treelist (parent widget).

I'd like to setup an Angular watcher, then trigger a `$broadcast` in my treelist `select event`. However, I keep running into this issue where I cannot inject `$scope` into a service or factory.

Factory code with treelist select event (see `dataModelOptions.change`):

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
.factory('TreeListDataModel', function (WidgetDataModel, widgetLinkingFactory) {

  function TreeListDataModel() {
  }

  TreeListDataModel.prototype = Object.create(WidgetDataModel.prototype);
  TreeListDataModel.prototype.constructor = WidgetDataModel;

  angular.extend(TreeListDataModel.prototype, {
    init: function () {

      // Kendo datasource object is initialized here...

      // KENDO TREELIST SELECT EVENT !!
      this.dataModelOptions.change = function (e) {
        var row = this.dataItem(this.select());

        var parentObj = _.find(this.dataItems(), { id: row.parentId });

        var dataModelOptions = {
          row: row,
          parentObj: parentObj,
          dimensions: this.options.dimensions, 
          fieldTypes: this.options.fieldTypes
        };

        // CANNOT DO THIS HERE - $SCOPE NOT AVAILABLE !!!
        $scope.$broadcast('refreshLinkedWidgets', dataModelOptions);

        widgetLinkingFactory.linkCharts(row, parentObj, this.options.dimensions, this.options.fieldTypes);
      },      
        this.updateScope(this.dataModelOptions);

    },
    updateScope: function (data) {
      this.dataModelOptions = data;
    },
    destroy: function () {
      WidgetDataModel.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
  });

  return TreeListDataModel;
});
```

And in my main directive code, I have no problem setting up the `watcher`:

```
 scope.$on('refreshLinkedWidgets', function (event, dataModelOptions) {
     // call my widgetLinkingFactory update code
 });
```

I'm experimenting with some ideas, so advice is appreciated.

regards,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory/service don't have `scope`. You can't do it on `scope`

But you can do it via injecting `rooScope` in your service.

Like this

Declare a method inside `TreeListDataModel` named `refreshLinkedWidgets`

then

```
$rootScope.$on("refreshLinkedWidgets", TreeListDataModel .refreshLinkedWidgets);
```

Sample code

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('TreeListDataModel', function (WidgetDataModel, widgetLinkingFactory,$rootScope) {

   var TreeListDataModel={
     refreshLinkedWidgets:refreshLinkedWidgets
   };
   function refreshLinkedWidgets(e,a){
      // some code
   }
   $rootScope.$on("refreshLinkedWidgets", TreeListDataModel .refreshLinkedWidgets);
    return TreeListDataModel;
}
```

Comment: oh my goodness, I didn't realize that I could inject `$rootScope`. I thought I had tried that. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Inject $rootScope and $broadcast from it.